# Read files from an encrypted disk?

Tags: encryption, terminal, usb, luks, disk-encryption

Is it possible to read from an LUKS-encrypted disk via the terminal, e.g. by booting from a live Linux system on a USB flash drive and accessing the encrypted host computer's hard drive?

Comment: Why not, if you can provide the key.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That's great! Would it be possible to somehow integrate this with tools such as `clonezilla`? The problem is that there exists no backup tool that can pull files from encrypted disks (or even hot-transfer!). You either have to do bit-by-bit cloning (which results in enormous backup volumes consisting mostly of unused/wasted space) - or - you first have to decrypt the entire disk, then copy file by file, then encrypt again both the source and backup drive. That's a **lot** of overhead